# React Navigation Tab Bar on the Side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm making an app and we're using React Navigation.

I know the tab bar has options for placement on the top and on the bottom of the screen ... but is there any way to put it on the side of the screen (and have the options display vertically)?

In my head I'd like this for larger tablet-sized devices, and then for smaller screens I'm hoping to use the drawer navigator so they display off-screen.

Comment: Whoops my mistake! 
I found this.


  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-segment-tab

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that's not what I'm asking for. I'm specifically asking about a way to customize the tab bar in React Navigation.

Comment: Well in that case, there is no way to make Native Tab Bar do that

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/) on react-navigation website. It even include almost all necessary code. You just need to change container `flexDirection` value.